# Cascaded split for more than one separator?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
"12:30-14:40".split("-")
```

Its output is:

```
["12:30", "14:40"]
```

I need to have and array like this:

```
[["12","30"],["14","40"]]
```

How can I do something equivalent of a *cascaded split* on the same line to get the second result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to iterate the resulting array again. In ECMAScript5 environments (node, modern browsers), `.map` works well for this:

```
"12:30-14:40".split("-").map(function(item) {
    return item.split(':');
});
```